# Update row in a dataframe based on a second one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, df1 :

```
                          AS  AT  CH  TR 
James Robert/01/08/2019   0   0   0   1 
James Robert/18/08/2019   0   0   0   1 
John Smith/01/08/2019     1   0   0   0 
John Smith/02/08/2019     0   1   0   0
```

And df2 :

```
                               TIME
Andrew Johnson/08/08/2019      1
James Robert/01/08/2019        0.5
John Smith/02/08/2019          1
```

If an index value is present in both dataframes (example : `James Robert/01/08/2019` and `John Smith/02/08/2019`), I would like to delete the row in df1 if the value of `df1["Column with a value"] - df2['TIME'] = 0` otherwise I would like to update the value.

The desired output would be :

```
                          AS  AT  CH  TR
James Robert/01/08/2019   0   0   0   0.5
James Robert/18/08/2019   0   0   0   1
John Smith/01/08/2019     1   0   0   0
```

If a row is in both dataframes, I'm able to delete it from df1, but I can't find a way to add this particular condition : `"df1["Column with a value"]"`

Thanks

Comment: Which column do you look into in df1 ? All of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using index use them as columns. Place the `df2['index']` column in a list. Use that list as parameter in isin method done in `df1`.

```
df2['index'] = df2.index
df1['index'] = df1.index

filtered_df1 = df1[df1['index'].isin(df2['index'].values.tolist())]
```

Create a dictionary with your `'index'` column and the value for your `'Time'` column from `df2` then map it to `filtered_df1`.

```
your_dict = dict(zip(df2['index'],df2['Time']))
filtered_df1['Subtract Value'] = filtered_df1['index'].map(your_dict).fillna(value = 0)
```

Then do the subtraction there.

```
final_df = filtered_df1.sub(filtered_df1['Subtract Value'], axis=0)
```

Hope this helps.